# What is the significance of the cat?

Tags: plot-explanation, way-of-the-dragon

In Way of the Dragon, Chuck Norris and Bruce Lee fight. This scene is not comedic; yet there are numerous cuts to a cat.

At one point at the end, the camera actually zooms in and out on the cat!

What is the importance of the cat?

Comment: I'd love an answer to this one! I always crack up when the cat shows up.

Comment: That scene is *incredibly* comedic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [*Bruce Lee: Incomparable Fighter*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Z4qHatHRJlsC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22way%20of%20the%20dragon%22%20cat&source=bl&ots=VYmoP9LefP&sig=NLYhZATVeO8hcGRcNl-H4SQbMpI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FVYLUKLEHKeQ2QWi-NXqDw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=had%20the%20film%20edited%20so%20that%20cat%27s&f=false) (M. Uyehara, 1988, p. 87), Bruce had the film edited so the cat's actions would "interrelate" to his (his toying with his opponent, for example, like the cat toys with the ball of paper), but it "didn't succeed in the finished product." At the time, this movie was the most expensive produced in a Chinese studio, at $150,000.